# Change polling rate / tickrate of on-key for big-bang in racket

Tags: racket

Say I have a function like this:

```
(define (key-handler dot-position key)
  (cond
    [(string=? key "right") (make-posn (modulo (+ 10 (posn-x dot-position)) (image-width PLAY-FIELD))
                                       (posn-y dot-position))]
    [(string=? key "left") (make-posn (modulo (- (posn-x dot-position) 10) (image-width PLAY-FIELD))
                                      (posn-y dot-position))]
    [(string=? key "up") (make-posn (posn-x dot-position)
                                    (modulo (- (posn-y dot-position) 10) (image-height PLAY-FIELD)))]
    [(string=? key "down")
     (make-posn (posn-x dot-position)
                (modulo (+ (posn-y dot-position) 10) (image-height PLAY-FIELD)))]
    [else dot-position]))
```

and then a function which draws the dot (but ultimately irrelevant to the question.)

Currently, my movement is very choppy when the key is being held down. I assume this is because on-key is being called at the default tickrate of racket. I tried increasing the on-tick speed to .01 to smooth this out, but it didn't make a difference.

How do I change specifically the rate at which on-key polls the keyboard for smoother movement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`big-bang` *doesn’t* “poll the keyboard”, which is the problem. Rather, it calls your `on-key` handler whenever the operating system delivers a key press event. When you hold a key on the keyboard down, the operating system *will* send many key press events, according to the rate at which you have configured key repeat on your computer, but this is not something you want to depend upon for anything other than allowing the user to type text.

Instead of relying on the operating system’s key repeat speed (which can vary wildly between computers, or even between users of the same computer), keep track of which keys are *currently pressed*, and use that information to update the player character’s position in your `on-tick` handler, which is executed on a reliable clock. For example, define a world state like this:

```
(struct world-state (player-posn keys))
(struct keys-state (up right down left))

(define initial-world (world-state initial-player-posn (keys-state #f #f #f #f)))
```

In your `on-key` handler, update the world state to change the relevant portion of `world-state-keys` to `#t`, and add a corresponding `on-release` handler to change the flag back to `#f` when the key is released. Then you can compute the player’s current velocity based on the set of keys pressed:

```
(struct velocity (x y))

(define (key-state->magnitude v)
  (if v 1 0))

(define (keys-state->velocity s)
  (velocity (- (key-state->magnitude (keys-state-right s))
               (key-state->magnitude (keys-state-left s)))
            (- (key-state->magnitude (keys-state-up s))
               (key-state->magnitude (keys-state-down s)))))
```

You can use that information in `on-tick` to update the player’s position at a reliable rate, instead of relying on the nondeterministic behavior of the operating system’s configured key repeat rate.